# Rational functions with trivial Weil symbols at every point

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Let $f, g$ be a pair of nonzero rational functions in $\mathbb{C}(t).$ For $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ let $a$ be multiplicity of $g(t)$ at $\lambda$ and $b$ -  multiplicity of $f(t)$ at $\lambda.$ Weil symbol of $f$ and $g$ at $\lambda$ is defined by the following formula:
$$
(f,g)_{\lambda}=(-1)^{ab}\frac{f^a}{g^b}(\lambda).
$$

**Question:** For which pairs of rational functions $f, g$ Weil symbol $
(f,g)_{\lambda}$ equals to $\pm1$ at every point $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}?$

It is easy to find some pairs of such functions. For every  $r(t)\in \mathbb{C}(t)$  we can take $f=r(t)^a(1-r(t))^b$ and $g=r(t)^c(1-r(t))^d.$

This problem can be generalized to arbitrary Riemann surfaces, but it is probably very hard, because nontrivial examples of such pairs of functions come from  $A-$polynomials of some knots.